# Sub Laplacian on the quaternion Heisenberg group $\mathbb{H}$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, operator-theory, eigenvalues, laplacian, heisenberg-groups

The sublaplacian is defined by $\mathcal{L}=-\left(X_{0}^{2}+X_{1}^{2}+X_{2}^{2}+X_{3}^{2}\right)$, which is independent of the choice of the orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{H}$. It is well known that the sublaplacian $\mathcal{L}$ is positive and essentially self-adjoint. Let $\mathcal{L}=\int_{0}^{\infty} \lambda d E(\lambda)$ be the spectral decomposition of $\mathcal{L}$. Then the restriction operator $P_{\lambda}$ for $\mathcal{L}$ is defined by

$$
P_{\lambda} f=\lim _{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{\varepsilon} \int_{\lambda}^{\lambda+\varepsilon} d E(\lambda) f
$$

for $f \in \mathscr{S}(\mathcal{N})$. Thus $f=\int_{0}^{\infty} P_{\lambda} f d \lambda$ where $P_{\lambda} f$ is an eigenfunction of $\mathcal{L}$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$.

I have read the above in a paper but I have some questions:

1. Why the operator $\mathcal{L}$ is independent of the choice of the orthonormal basis?
2. why $P_{\lambda} f$ is an eigenfunction of $\mathcal{L}$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$?
   Thank you very much for your help in advance.